# Issue while loading the data in hive

Tags: hive

While loading the data in hive I am getting following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask

I have some data in hdfs and I am trying to load that data in hive.

following command I run on ambari hive cli:

```
1- create table currency_new(CurrencyId int,ThreeLetterIsoCode string,Name string, Rate bigint,LastUpdate bigint, Active string);

successfully created table currency_new

2- load data inpath '/usr/core/currency' into table currency_new;
error:"java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask"
```

What can I do?

Comment: Try from the command line

Answer (score -1):

Are you using a local path or an HDFS path? If you are using a local path, try with:

```
load data local inpath '/usr/core/currency' into table currency_new;
```

Comment: No I am using hdfs path